# How can I use one of the undefined handles in my C program on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, handle, cmd

A password-prompting function in a closed-source library I'm using in my C program on Windows XP writes the prompt to `stdout` (handle 1) and any error messages to `stderr` (handle 2).

Now, I want to be able to redirect the output *my functions* produce using the normal redirection operators.

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) the handles 3-9 *"are defined individually by the application"*. It seems to me I could use one of these in my program and then use the normal redirection operators (e.g. something like `myprogram.exe 3| otherprogram.exe`).

How can I do this in my C code?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to pipe some of the output of my functions to another program. Since this password-prompting function that I don't have any control over can write to both stdout and stderr I thought I could use one of the other handles. But how can I use them? stdout and stderr are predefined and can be easily used with `fprintf`. The others can't: Code like `fprintf(3, ...` crashes my program.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows? Well, if you use the posix compatibility library, you could use 'dup2' to force the use of file descriptor 3. I can't promise that cmd.exe would know what you are talking about.

Fundamentally, here, you are looking at a tiny bit of Unix/Linux-envy on Windows. The concept of small-integer descriptor numbers is a basic Unix/Linux thing. It's *not* a feature of windows. The fact that cmd.exe knows what to do with 0, 1, and 2 is most likely a convenience for misplaced Unix shell programmers which is not generalized to other numbers.

Comment: The microsoft.com site I linked ([this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)) gives examples of using handles higher than 2 in cmd.exe. There has to be some way to use these handles in a C program.

Comment: Then it's the posix compatibility library, and dup2, for you.